# Would one piece film gold be cannon

Tags: one-piece

Wouldn't film gold be cannon i don't see anyone ever mentioning that we saw Tesoro ship in episode 750 of one piece during the end of silver miner arch

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. This question has already been asked and answered before. Hopefully, they help your understanding :)

Comment: Canon in anime continuity? There isn't any Silver Mine arc in manga continuity.